# Working script gives error when getting more lines from get-connector

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, get

I have written a code to get data from a getconnector. While getting data from 15 days everything works fine, but when getting data from 30 days I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\source\repos\Cabman Get-All\Cabman Get-All\Cabman_Get_All.py", line 
  46, in <module>
    jsondata = json.loads(data.content)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfrap0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra80\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The code I use for writing the JSON data to a file looks like this:

```
data = requests.get(url_data, headers = {'Host': 'services.%%%.com', 'Authorization': 'earer ' + acces_token})
    status = data.status_code
    jsondata = json.loads(data.content)
    if status == 200:
        desired_dir = "B:\Cabman"
        full_path = os.path.join(desired_dir, x+'.json')
        with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
            json_string=json.dumps(jsondata, indent=4)
            f.write(json_string)
        print(x + " succesvol opgehaald.")
    else: 
        print("Error at "+ x)
        print(status)
```

Het raw-data I get from the get-connector looks like below (personal data is masked with %%%):

```
b'[{"shiftNumber":null,"egateShiftID":%%%,"weeknumber":6,"day":"zaterdag","hostId":7231,"driverCode":%%%,"driverName":"%%%","vehicleId":2751,"vehicleNr":"2270","licensePlate":"%%%","ShiftStart":"2023-02-11T07:58:33","FirstMovementTimeStamp":"2023-02-11T07:59:06","FirstTripTimeStamp":null,"diffLogonAndFirstMovement":0,"shiftStartLocation":{"latitude":0,"longitude":0},"LastMovementBeforeLogoffTimeStamp":"2023-02-11T08:00:36","ShiftEnd":"2023-02-11T08:01:47","diffLogoffAndLastMovement":1,"shiftEndLocation":{"latitude":%%%,"longitude":%%%},
```

The final JSON files look like below (personal data is masked with %%%):

```
[
    {
        "shiftNumber": null,
        "egateShiftID": %%%,
        "weeknumber": 4,
        "day": "zondag",
        "hostId": 7231,
        "driverCode": %%%,
        "driverName": "%%%",
        "vehicleId": 2380,
        "vehicleNr": "1866",
        "licensePlate": "%%%",
        "ShiftStart": "2023-01-29T06:34:44",
        "FirstMovementTimeStamp": null,
        "FirstTripTimeStamp": null,
        "diffLogonAndFirstMovement": null,
        "shiftStartLocation": {
            "latitude": %%%,
            "longitude": %%%
        },
        "LastMovementBeforeLogoffTimeStamp": "2023-01-28T23:13:24",
        "ShiftEnd": "2023-01-29T06:59:14",
        "diffLogoffAndLastMovement": 465,
        "shiftEndLocation": {
```

It seems there's a problem with the the line  'jsondata = json.loads(data.content)' but this part works fine with smaller quantities of data. It does not seem to be an probleem with the data source as the get statement ( data = requests.get) is not giving an error.

Comment: Just a guess: you db is returning an error message that is not in json format. When you `print(data.content)` what do you see?

Comment: `data.content` is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Maurice Meyer, Could you please explain my why it works with slower data quantities?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the statement 'print(data.content)' gives the following output b'[{"shiftNumber":null,"egateShiftID":7969.....

Comment: @Catscanner: I dont know your data, you need to debug it.

Comment: That's not JSON format, it's the output of a python `print()` when the argument is a byte string.

Comment: @Barmar that is what MauriceMeyer asked for. To me it lookes like a dictionary which should be easily  converted to JSON.

Comment: It looks to me like a list containing a dictionary that has been converted to a byte string. E.g. the server did something like `socket.write(str(list_of_dicts).encode())`.

Comment: The server should do `socket.write(json.dumps(list_of_dicts).encode())`.

Comment: I have added extra informatie to my question. I hope this makes it easier to find a possible solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved. The issue was not in the code itself but in the limits of the server on the other side. The amount of data is simply to big when pulling 30 days.